# General discussion: non-informative error messages

Tags: error-handling

I would like to ask a general developer public:

Why do most of the error and warning messages say so little?

A message that says only something like `Operation not permitted` provides no meaningful information. Even worse is `Oops, something went bad :(`.
Is there any rational reason to have such short and non-informative messages?
Why not provide a set of 3 key information?

1. What is wrong?
2. Why is that wrong and how can it be fixed?
3. Where can I find more info? (documentation etc)

For systems that have tiny displays, or low memory, that totally makes sense just to display a numerical code or short message, but web applications, normal computer programs, etc? This is only frustrating.